# Highcharts Selection Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

For some reason, I can't seem to get the selection event to work in Highcharts.  Some non-trivial googling/poking around isn't showing me a working sample (even the JSFiddle from them isn't working for me in Mac Chrome/Safari/Firefox).  Here's a quick fiddle to poke at...

http://jsfiddle.net/qwfZ9/3/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, much later, I have stumbled across the answer.  Among other things...

Pie charts don't use selection events.  Certainly not the top level "events" selection, at least.  You have to use

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        events: {
            click: function (event) {
                alert("You clicked on the pie!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vL7Q4/1/